# Fast conversion with dictionary or lookup table

Tags: python, optimization

I'm trying to convert a string of amino acids into numbers to use for training a neural network in pytorch. More specifically, I'm looking for the best way to convert a string to numbers with a lookup table or dictionary. The key is that it is done fast, since it needs to be done many times.

As an example.

I have a sequence:

```
seq = 'KLALDIEIATYRKLLEGEENRITIPVQTFSNLQIRETSLDTKSVSEGHLKRNIVVKTVEMRDGEVRRDLGPVRLWLAPGILKARPWRKAWGWHIEGSQQLPVAPQGILEESKETECNSVSSVPP'
```

and I wish to convert the string into a list of numbers using the following lookup table:

```
    #    A R N D C Q E G H I  L  K  M  F  P  S  T  W  Y  V  B  Z  X  *  -  ?
    #    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 0
```

I was thinking of building a dictionary with the lookup table, converting the string to a list of letters and then looping through this list and applying the dictionary on each letter, but I'm wondering whether there is a better way of doing this?

More specifically my approach currently looks like this:

```
seq = 'KLALDIEIATYRKLLEGEENRITIPVQTFSNLQIRETSLDTKSVSEGHLKRNIVVKTVEMRDGEVRRDLGPVRLWLAPGILKARPWRKAWGWHIEGSQQLPVAPQGILEESKETECNSVSSVPP'
codes = {'?':0, 'A':1, 'R':2, 'N':3, 'D':4, 'C':5, 'Q':6, 'E':7, 'G':8, 'H':9, 'I':10, 'L':11, 'K':12, 'M':13, 'F':14, 'P':15, 'S':16, 'T':17, 'W':18, 'Y':19, 'V':20, 'B':21, 'Z':22, 'X':23, '*':24, '-':25}
seq_list = list(seq)
output = [codes[i] for i in seq_list ]
```

Comment: How do you derive that table? Are letters assigned randomly, or is there an underlying pattern?

Comment: The table is static, and will just be defined once. It can be defined anyway we want, I chose the above conversion since it is similar to the one matlab can do.

Comment: Yes, you should use `map` with a dictionary

Comment: That’s about the way to do it in pure Python, but if this operation is a bottleneck, you’ll probably see a lot of improvement from performing it in C, for example. (Or maybe libraries that keep loops out of Python, like numpy, can get you close enough.) Plus it’s probably better to use an array instead of a dict (in either case) to save on hashing and hash table overhead, since your alphabet is tightly packed.

Comment: You don't need to convert `seq` to a list. You can just use `for i in seq`.

Comment: Does python have `ORD(character)` yielding the ascii number?

Comment: Dictionary lookups are very fast

Comment: @RickJames [Yes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - Might it be faster to use `ord` instead of a "lookup"?

Comment: @RickJames How do you propose to utilize `ord` in solving this problem? I see no obvious use for it.

Comment: @Rick James The OP would have to change his pytorch program to use ASCII numbers instead of the current lookup table, but that lookup table looks like it has been carefully crafted. If this was a possibility, `ord` is almost as fast of a solution, and converting to ASCII by doing `[x for x in bytes(seq, "ascii")]` is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be overcomplicating things a bit regarding your approach, but this is a solution with `map` as commented:

```
codify_table = ['A','R','N','D','C','Q','E','G','H','I','L','K','M','F','P','S','T','W','Y','V','B','Z','X','*','-']
values_table = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 0]
lookup_table = {codify_table[i]:values_table[i] for i in range(len(codify_table))}
seq = 'KLALDIEIATYRKLLEGEENRITIPVQTFSNLQIRETSLDTKSVSEGHLKRNIVVKTVEMRDGEVRRDLGPVRLWLAPGILKARPWRKAWGWHIEGSQQLPVAPQGILEESKETECNSVSSVPP'
new_seq = [x for x in map(lambda x: lookup_table[x],seq)]
print(new_seq)
```

And the output is too long, but seems to match the required one

Regarding Barmar's approach, and what he suggests is not to previously use `list(seq)` but instead simply use it in the list comprehension:

```
output = [codes[i] for i in seq]
```

Also, this doesn't provide any advantage (using map) as seen in the average times below:

```
Method 1 time: 9.751319885253906e-05
Method 2 time: 6.67572021484375e-05
```

Finally, as conclusion, unless there's a better technique, the method you are using is best regarding time.

Comment: There’s no need to convert the result of `map` to a list in order to iterate over it. Also, it’s generally considered better style to use a comprehension than `map` with a lambda (also shorter and more efficient). Also also, the question says the desired result is just the list, not a string again.

Comment: Ah, my bad and thank you for the suggestions, I'll edit the answer as to much the desired output. Times have also been edited to match the new code being tested

Answer (score 1):

I have found an interesting way of achieving your goal, using only string built-ins (particularly the [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) static method). It requires that you rewrite your lookup table a bit:

```
newcodes = {key: f" {str(val)} " for key, val in codes.items()}  # Make the values of the LUT strings 
transtable = str.maketrans(newcodes)  # Create translation table
output = seq.translate(transtable).split()  # Translate and split to obtain list
```

Or if you want the output to be a list of integers:

```
output = [int(x) for x in seq.translate(transtable).split()]
```

Obviously one needs to create the translation table only once.